# Entering default value of string in database

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I am trying to enter a default value of a string row in my database, using ASP.NET Visual Studio. I am simply trying to have "NotSet" as default but I get this error when trying to update the database:

> The name "NotSet" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions
>   are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
>   Column names are not permitted.

I still have trouble understanding what kind of values are permitted, though. The datatype is "nchar(10)" and nulls are allowed. There's nothing else to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure NotSet is in quotes in your sql statement

```
'NotSet'
```